# Why is my process.env not working properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, environment-variables

I am practicing MongoDB, which requires you to connect your terminal to MongoDB Atlas using a connection string.
I am storing the credential parts of my connection string in .env file but it shows authentication error when I do that.

```
import express from "express";
import Cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
const app = express(); 
const port = process.env.PORT;
const connection_url = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.USERNAME}:${process.env.PASSSWORD}@clustername.eksth.mongodb.net/testdatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(Cors());

mongoose.connect(connection_url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
mongoose.connection.on("error", function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
mongoose.connection.on("open", function () {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB Database");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("hi"));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on localhost:${port}`));
```

The `process.env.PORT` works perfectly fine but not the string.

Error I am getting:

```
MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
```

Comment: Watch out of the typo in `PASSSWORD` (there are 3 'S')

Comment: you can simply save the complete url in environment file `mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.something.mongodb.net/dbname`

Comment: this did the job for me